# Ruby On rails: Cannot convert String to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I am running rake db:migrate on Windows command line in my Project folder..

I am getting this non descriptive error: **Cannot convert String to Integer**

I've posted the full trace of this error below:

```
D:\Rails\MyBlog>rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
can't convert String into Integer
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/l
ib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/l
ib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_c
onnection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connec
tion'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in check
out'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in conne
ction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_conne
ction'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:863:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/acti
ve_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.r
b:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

D:\Rails\MyBlog>
```

How can I solve this?? Any Ideas?

**EDIT**

My Code:

```
class CreateBlogPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :blog_posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :content
      t.datetime :publishDate

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Database.yml**

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: gts
  username: heuro
  password: userPass
  host: 'localhost'
  port: '3306'
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: gts
    username: heuro
    password: userPass
    host: '127.0.0.1'
    port: '3306'

production:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: gts
    username: heuro
    password: userPass
    host: '127.0.0.1'
    port: '3306'
```

Comment: Only error, is not enough to help you out.. Need to see the code also.

Comment: Are you talking about database.yml file?

Comment: yes, you may have an issue with `database.yml`

Comment: You created a migration and updated some migration source in the migration folder? Check there for proper syntax. Without any additional info, I'd say the likelihood is a problem there.

Comment: I've edited the question.. Can you please see the problem for me.. I'm very frsutated by these errors.. Very very new to rails

Comment: Using RubyMine 5.4 as my IDE..

Comment: Can you post a gist with your code like client.rb or application.rb? It looks like the problem may be there.

Comment: Hi Brian.. I am very new to this.. I am unaware of horrifying terms like gist.. Btw.. I cannot find any clinet.rb on my machine.. I've already posted the content of migrate folder which rails created for me

Comment: @BrianMikeyHalbert, `client.rb` is part of the mysql2 gem, not his project code.

Comment: show your `Create_blog_posts.rb` which will be in your app/models/ folder.

Comment: In "DB" folder I can only see Three things.. 1) "Migrate Folder" 2) development.sqlite3 and seeds.rb

Comment: Hi uDaY.. It has nothing except a simple class.. class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb) for the mysql2 gem, I think your problem might be that you have the port as a string in your YAML file.

Try changing it to look like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: gts
  username: heuro
  password: userPass
  host: 'localhost'
  port: 3306
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Didnt knew such a simple chnage will make it work.. You are god..! :) You saved me.. :)

Comment: Glad that worked! It always helps to check the source to figure out how things like this work, and why exactly they're breaking.

Comment: I'll take care in future.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your database.yml file to make it look as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: gts
  user: heuro
  password: userPass
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```